# Overlap text by another text in XeLaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, xetex, rotating

I need to overlap a text on page like on pic, but have no idea how.
I know about block rotation by graphicx. I tried rotate it by tikz, but it put rotated text between lines.
[image: required result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick-and-dirty way: the trick is to use `overlay` to hide the size of the text to LaTeX. You have to adjust manually the coordinates, though.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}


% This is attached to the start of the paragraph, do not insert
% blank lines
\tikz[overlay, scale=2, transform shape] 
     \node [font=\Huge\bfseries, rotate=15] at (3,-.5) {PASSED!}; 
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can easily play with opacity and color too:

```latex
\tikz[overlay, scale=2, transform shape, opacity=0.5]
     \node [red, font=\Huge\bfseries, rotate=15] at (3,-.5) {FAILED!};
\lipsum[4]
```

[image]